# Draw a graph in Latex with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-arrows, graphs

I am interested in outputting  this graph in  latex using tikz:

[image]

So far I got this:

[image]

and my tikz code is

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (A) at (0,0) {A};
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (B) at (0,3) {B};
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (C) at (2.5,4) {C};
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (D) at (2.5,1) {D};
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (E) at (2.5,-3) {E};
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (F) at (5,3) {F} ;

    \path [->] (A) edge node[left] {$5$} (B);
    \path [->](B) edge node[left] {$3$} (C);
    \path [->](A) edge node[left] {$4$} (D);
    \path [->](D) edge node[left] {$3$} (C);
    \path [->](A) edge node[right] {$3$} (E);
    \path [->](D) edge node[left] {$3$} (E);
    \path [->](D) edge node[top] {$3$} (F);
    \path [->](C) edge node[top] {$5$} (F);
    \path [->](E) edge node[right] {$8$} (F);   
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I want to know how to draw the arc between nodes B and E and also thicker  arcs with their lengths in center. Any help is appreciated

Comment: For the arc, try `\draw[->] (B) to [bend right=20] (E);`. If the bend doesn't look right you can change the 20 to a different number.

Comment: @DavidRobertson I did something like this based on your input
\path [->](B) edge[bend right=60] node[left] {$1$} (E);

Answer (score 69, accepted):

One suggestion, borrowing from David Robertson's comment. A couple of `scope`s are added, to set the same style easily for all the nodes within them. The weights are set in the center of the line (so `left`, `above` etc. are removed), and filled with white, to cover the underlying line. If you really want that, the `arrows.meta` library lets you set the arrow tip in a different color than the lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,thick,draw}]
    \node (A) at (0,0) {A};
    \node (B) at (0,3) {B};
    \node (C) at (2.5,4) {C};
    \node (D) at (2.5,1) {D};
    \node (E) at (2.5,-3) {E};
    \node (F) at (5,3) {F} ;
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[>={Stealth[black]},
              every node/.style={fill=white,circle},
              every edge/.style={draw=red,very thick}]
    \path [->] (A) edge node {$5$} (B);
    \path [->] (B) edge node {$3$} (C);
    \path [->] (A) edge node {$4$} (D);
    \path [->] (D) edge node {$3$} (C);
    \path [->] (A) edge node {$3$} (E);
    \path [->] (D) edge node {$3$} (E);
    \path [->] (D) edge node {$3$} (F);
    \path [->] (C) edge node {$5$} (F);
    \path [->] (E) edge node {$8$} (F); 
    \path [->] (B) edge[bend right=60] node {$1$} (E); 
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```